# Regression Activation Mapping for a given CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression, conv-neural-network

This paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10757.pdf disucces using Regression Activation Mapping (RAM) - instead of Class Activation Mapping (CAM). There are several articles describing how to implement CAM. But i cant find any for RAM - or the code used in the paper.

Anyone got code example of RAM?

Update: 
Looking at this example: http://www.hackevolve.com/where-cnn-is-looking-grad-cam/

What should line 16 and 17 be when pred is a scalar?

```
class_idx = np.argmax(preds[0])
class_output = model.output[:, class_idx]
```

edit: repository for the Diabetic Retinopathy Detection paper: https://github.com/cauchyturing/kaggle_diabetic_RAM

edit2: changed title from InceptionV3 to any CNN architecture

Comment: For InceptionV4 the width and height goes from (299,299) to (147,147) -> (73,73) -> (71,71) -> (35,35) -> (17,17) -> (8,8). So using a RAM like in the paper above will result in a (8,8) resolution image.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is not a very big difference between RAM and CAM. They all use the weight of the global average pooling layer.

Comment: the difference is still that at the end you have a dense layer where every neuron represents a class for classification while for regression you have only one neuron.
Does that make a difference? fis it necessary to have the neurons per class before you can analyze which feature map was significant?

Answer (score 0):

One of the more popular Grad-CAM libraries - specific to pytorch - is Jacob Gil's: https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam/ .
One of the output targets ([BinaryClassifierOutputTarget](https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam/blob/master/pytorch_grad_cam/utils/model_targets.py#L26)) can readily be used for regression activation mapping, as mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam/issues/360.

Comment: Please post an answer and then references for more details.